# Button click event issue in angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

⁮I am trying to apply a "disable option" to my custom button, but when I set the button to disabled, the click event is still working. I only need the click event if the button is enabled, and not if it is disabled.

Code:

```
<myngbutton [disabled]="disabled3" (click)="alertMsg()">Save 3</myngbutton>
```

Comment: The problem is in your custom button implementation not with logic. Works fine with normal button.

Comment: You can see my all codes in my stackblitz..Please check my stackblitz link

Comment: @Arcteezy:- I do not know How do it..If you know please tell me..update my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `click` event you are subscribing to, isn't the `click` event on the button element, but a click on the `myngbutton` element.
You need to add an event emitter on your `myngbutton` component that emits on `button` element clicks:

myngbutton.component.ts:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyngbuttonComponent {
   [...]

   @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter();
   [...]

}
```

myngbutton.component.html:

```
<button [...] (click)="onClick.emit()">[...]</button>
```

app.component.html:

```
<myngbutton [disabled]="disabled1" (onClick)="alertMsg()">Save 1</myngbutton>
```

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: I have added disabled property but not working..I think render issue? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean? The stackblitz version is working.

Comment: Can i use click instead of onClick?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `myngbutton` is not a html native element, it won't act like a native button. It is considered as a custom element with as parent type HtmlElement.

The `disabled` html attribute only works with the elements described in the [W3School documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp). This means that if you want your component to act like a button, then you will need to program it. Or use a native `<button>` inside your component.

Here is an example:

```
<!-- Won't enter the alertMsg method if it is disabled -->    
<myngbutton [disabled]="disabled3" (click)="!disabled3 && alertMsg()">Save 3</myngbutton>
```